# how to stop ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, clearinterval

I have multiple ajax requests and when one of them can't get data I want , I re-send it until it can get data .
the problem that I can't stop it after it gets data . Is there's a break or something equivalent to it in ajax ? 
I tried clearinterval but it didn't work 
here's my functions :

```
  function ajaxGetServerDatabase(Div,val,interval){
       console.log(val);
       dbs[val]=new Array();
        $('#bck_action').val('get_DB');
        $('#server_ip').val(val);
        post_data = $('#'+Div+' *').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: document.URL,
            data: post_data,

            dataType: "text",
            success: function(response) {

                if (response!='no_connection'){
                    dbs[val]=JSON.parse(response)
                    clearInterval(this.interval);  // ???? 
                }

            }
        });
        return false;
    }

  function ajaxGetDatabase(Div,ips,interval){
    $.each(ips,function(i,val){
       dbs[val]=new Array();
        $('#bck_action').val('get_DB');
        $('#server_ip').val(val);
        post_data = $('#'+Div+' *').serialize();
        //    console.log(post_data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: document.URL,
            data: post_data,

            dataType: "text",
            success: function(response) {

                if (response!='no_connection'){
                    dbs[val]=JSON.parse(response)
                }
                else
               {
                   setInterval("ajaxGetServerDatabase('"+Div+"','"+val+"','"+interval+"')", interval);
               }
            }
        });
    });

    return false;
}
```

I call it :

```
  ajaxGetDatabase('tab_backup',ips,3000);
```

Comment: There's an `abort()` function for XHR, but once it's sent, it's sent.

Comment: I have other ajax requests in my page , if I use it would they be sent or it's kill the ajax ?

Comment: You'd use abort() on a specific XHR object, it does'nt abort all of them!

Comment: I don't know what XHR means  , I will google it . thanks

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: 1.7 . solution is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the answer :
in ajaxGetDatabase :

```
 success: function(response) {

                if (response!='no_connection'){
                    dbs[val]=JSON.parse(response)

                }
                else
                {
                 id=setInterval("ajaxGetServerDatabase('"+Div+"','"+val+"')", interval);
            }
```

in ajaxGetServerDatabase :

```
    success: function(response) {
            if (response!='no_connection'){
                dbs[val]=JSON.parse(response)
                clearInterval(id);
            }

        }
```

with out scope parameter

```
 var id;
```

to make it general and work for more than one server had stopped (more than one ajax request is failed) I used an array to save ids like this :

```
   var ids=new Array();

   ids[val]=setInterval("ajaxGetServerDatabase('"+Div+"','"+val+"')", interval);

   clearInterval(ids[val]);
```

Comment: This is your solution answer?

Comment: yes , this is my solution , but I can't accept in until two days

Comment: @esimov do you know a way for stoping all those ajax requests when refreshing page or changing page ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = null;
function ajaxGetServerDatabase(Div,val,interval){
   //...
   if (response!='no_connection'){
                dbs[val]=JSON.parse(response)
                clearInterval(timer);  // ???? 
            }
   //....
   else
           {
               timer = setInterval("ajaxGetServerDatabase('"+Div+"','"+val+"','"+interval+"')", interval);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

`clearInterval` has nothing to do with `ajax`. It's only a timer function which scope is to clear the timer set earlier with `setInterval`. If you really want to use a timer function you need either to attach a variable to the `setInterval` function, which you can clear with `clearInterval` setting as a parameter the id defined earlier in the `setInterval`.

```
var id = " ";
success: function(response) {

   if (response!='no_connection'){
       dbs[val]=JSON.parse(response)
       clearInterval(id);
   }
   else                   
       id= setInterval("ajaxGetServerDatabase('"+Div+"','"+val+"','"+interval+"')", interval);
}
```

Or you can abort the code with ajax `abort`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something close to this?

```
...
var stopAjax = 0;  //switch is on
if(stopAjax == 0){

  $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(response) {
    if (response!='no_connection'){
       dbs[val]=JSON.parse(response);
       stopAjax = 1; //switch is off
    }
    else{
        setInterval("ajaxGetServerDatabase('"+Div+"','"+val+"','"+interval+"')", interval);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What is the the the "function(response)" returning when it gets no data? I was thinking using "error: function()" might help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `timeout` setting perhaps? eg

```
$.ajax({
    timeout: 10000,
    ...
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/